# Can I create cocos2d animations without using Xcode?

Tags: animation, cocos2d, xcode

I need to have someone do animation work for an iOS game I'm developing (using cocos2d), however this person does not have a Mac and as such cannot run Xcode.

Is there a way for them to create animations for me without the use of Xcode?

Comment: If you only need sprite animations then the person can create the sprite animation using flash or some such software. If you want him to script animation for you that works with cocos2d and he does not have xCode then he can definitely write the code in a text file and pass that over to you... but he will not be able to check whether those scripts or code works since he cannot compile them.

Comment: @Jamornh This answers my question. (The answer if I understand correctly being No.) I appreciate the alternate solution, that helps me quite a bit.  Thanks.  Is there a reason you posted it as a comment?  I would be willing to mark it as the answer.

Comment: I didn't know if that was exactly what you were asking for, so I didn't post it as a direct answer. I've cleaned up the comment and bit and posted it as the answer now below. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, if you are referring to writing Objective-C using the Cocos2D framework to do animations, your animator will not be able to do so without xCode. He could write the code in a text file and pass that to you, but will not be able to compile them to check that they do work (which really defeats the purpose I suppose.)

However, if you only need sprite animations then the person can create the sprite animation using flash or some such software (then export the PNG of each frame for you.) Then you can use those animation frames in your app.

Comment: This does answer the question.  Thanks.  For future readers with the same or a similar problem this also helped me a lot: http://www.benoitfreslon.com/tutorial-export-your-flash-animations-on-iphoneipad-with-cocos2d-and-texturepacker